# Page refresh in Angular with stateparams and html5 mode goes back to home

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have made a website in Angular with html5 mode on. The routing works fine except for the subpages that uses stateparams. When I for example refresh the site with mysite.com/team/john where john is a stateparam Angular routes the website back to home. Ho do I fix this?

This is what I have in the routerprovider

```
$stateProvider
    .state('team',{
        url: '/team/:member',
        templateUrl: '/partials/profile.html',
        controller: 'TeamCtrl as team',
    })
```

Thanks!

Comment: server isn't routing properly. Sounds like you are doing redirect and not maintaining the url while outputting the index.html

Comment: What do you mean by that? Other pages that don't use stateparams works fine and doesn't route back to index.html

Comment: in that case suggest putting `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', func(...` in  run block of app and see if it is being triggered. Find out if angular is doing it or server is